# cancel array Input Box

Tags: arrays, vbscript, inputbox

I am trying to make the cancel function work for my array it works for a simple input box but Array(InputBox( does not like it very much.

Working code.

```
If strVarValue = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox ("User canceled!")
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

What I need help with

```
strIPAddress = Array(InputBox("IP address"))
If strIPAddress = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox ("User canceled!")
    WScript.Quit
End If
```

Doesn't like the Array hence why I'm getting type mismatch.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is `Array(InputBox("IP address"))` supposed to achieve? You'll just get an array with a single string element.

Comment: That's a very good question and you've just help me solve my problem, The array was used to pass the values, not to enter so yeah I spotted the problem.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Do the conversion only if the user did not press "Cancel":

```
userInput = InputBox("IP address")
If userInput = "" Then
    MsgBox ("User canceled!")
    WScript.Quit
End If

strIPAddress = Array(userInput)
```

Also, if you want to distinguish between "user pressed Cancel" and "user pressed OK without entering a value" you need to check if the variable is `Empty`:

```
userInput = InputBox("IP address")
If IsEmpty(userInput) Then
    MsgBox ("User canceled!")
    WScript.Quit
ElseIf userInput = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Missing input!")
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

strIPAddress = Array(userInput)
```